# Retrieving data from a particular column in a CSV File using TCL

Tags: data-structures, tcl

I have a CSV File,containing two columns of data.
I want to retrieve two columns of the data in two separate lists.

I have tried the following code:

```
set fp [open "D:\\RWTH\\Mini thesis\\EclipseTCL\\TCL trial\\excelv1.csv" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp
set data [split $file_data " "]

puts $data
```

the **output** obtained is

```
{0,245
0.0025,249
0.005,250
0.0075,252
0.01,253
0.0125,255
0.015,256
.
.
.
}
```

The data is in 2 separate columns in the excel sheet. I wish to take the elements only from the 2nd column i,e

```
{245,
249,
250,
252,
253,
.
.
.
}
```

I would be glad, if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `file_data` you have already read from the file, you can:

```
lmap row [split [string trim $file_data] \n] {
    scan $row %*f,%d
}
```

That is, trim off white space before and after the data, split into rows, then from every row, scan one integer (skipping the real and the comma). All the scanned integers are collected in a list.

It is, however, a good idea to always use the right tool for the job.

```
package require csv

lmap row [split [string trim $file_data] \n] {
    lindex [::csv::split $row] end
}
```

The `::csv::split` command knows exactly how to split csv data. In this case, it isn't really necessary, but it's a good habit to use the `csv` package for csv data.

Documentation:
[csv (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to use "gets" to read each line from the file:

```
set fp [open "D:\\RWTH\\Mini thesis\\EclipseTCL\\TCL trial\\excelv1.csv" r]
set secondColumnData {}
while {[gets $fp line]>=0} {
    if {[llength $line]>0} {
        lappend secondColumnData [lindex [split $line ","] 1]
    }
}
close $fp 
puts $secondColumnData
```

[gets](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
set data [read [open "D:\\RWTH\\Mini thesis\\EclipseTCL\\TCL trial\\excelv1.csv"]]
set result [regexp -all -inline -line -- {^.*,(.*)$} $data]
set items {}
foreach {tmp item} $result {
  lappend items $item
}
puts $items
```

Output:

```
245 249 250 252 253 255 256
```